# Running django sites on two ports with apache

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, rake, edx

I am running the edx open source platform on an ec2 instance.
It consists of two platforms:

```
1. lms: runs on 0.0.0.0:80
2. cms: runs on 0.0.0.0:81
```

There started with the following command

```
rake lms and rake cms respectively
```

It's actually a django application (mostly), but i think it is this way because rakefiles are used to provide some more configurations (not really sure)

Since the django server is not meant to be used in production, i want to use apache to run the two services.

Can anyone guide me to do this?
Thanks already :)